# Change the column type to 'Date' from 'Character varying' in PostgreSQL 11.0

Tags: postgresql, date

I have a postgreSQL 11.0 table with dates in below format, but the column type 'character varying'.

```
id        primary_completion_date 
0         December2019
1         April2020
2         September2021
3         September2022
4         December2021
```

Is it possible to convert the column type to 'date'. When I try to convert it to date, It changes the column content to below:

```
id        primary_completion_date
0         12-2019-01
1         04-2020-01
2         09-2021-01
3         09-2022-01
4         12-2021-01
```

I am using following statement in my script.

```
alter table tbl alter primary_completion_date type date using to_date(primary_completion_date, 'MonthYYYY')
```

How can I retain the column content as the input but change the column type to 'Date'.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I retain the column content as the input but change the column type to 'Date'*"

You can't because `December2019` is not a valid value for a `date` column.

But you can always *format* the `date` value when you retrieve it:

```
select id, to_char(primary_completion_date, 'MonthYYYY') as formatted_completion_date
from the_table
```